# How to make a new column with conditions on another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a `cat_month` column in my `expeditions` dataframe. This column would contain the mountain category (small, medium or large) and I would like to assign a category according to the height contained in the `highpoint_metres` column (with quartiles: small = height lower than the first quartile) but I can't manage to do it.

Data:

```
import pandas as pd
expeditions = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/expeditions.csv")
```

What I've tried :

```
peaks[cat_monts] = 
for peak_id in expeditions : 
 if "highpoint_metres" < 6226.5 : #1er quartile 
  return "petite montagne"
elif 6226.5<"highpoint_metres" <7031.25:
  return "moyenne montagne"
else : 
 return "grande montagne"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) which accepts a list of conditions, list of their corresponding values, and a default ("else") value.

The conditions are evaluated in order, so you can use this:

```
conditions = {
    'moyenne montagne': expeditions['highpoint_metres'] < 7031.25,
    'petite montagne': expeditions['highpoint_metres'] < 6226.5,
}
expeditions['cat_month'] = np.select(conditions.values(), conditions.keys(), default='grande montagne')
```

Output:

```
      expedition_id  ...  highpoint_metres  ...         cat_month
0         ANN260101  ...            7937.0  ...   grande montagne
1         ANN269301  ...            7937.0  ...   grande montagne
2         ANN273101  ...            7937.0  ...   grande montagne
3         ANN278301  ...            7000.0  ...  moyenne montagne
4         ANN279301  ...            7160.0  ...   grande montagne
...             ...  ...               ...  ...               ...
10359     PUMO19101  ...            7138.0  ...   grande montagne
10360     PUMO19102  ...            7138.0  ...   grande montagne
10361     PUTH19101  ...            6350.0  ...  moyenne montagne
10362     RATC19101  ...            6600.0  ...  moyenne montagne
10363     SANK19101  ...            6452.0  ...  moyenne montagne
```

Comment: It gives this error : KeyError: 'height_metres'

Comment: @UserCitron in your question you wrote `height_metres`, but it's not in the dataframe. did you mean `highpoint_metres`?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry, I got confused with another column in another dataframe, I will replace with highpoint_metres

Answer (score 2):

One option is the `case_when` function from `pyjanitor`:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
expeditions.case_when(
    # condition, value if True
    expeditions.highpoint_metres < 7031.25, 'moyenne montagne',
    expeditions.highpoint_metres < 6226.5, 'petite montagne',
    'grande montagne', # default if False
    column_name = 'cat_month')
```

A faster option for this kind of scenario, than `case_when` or `np.select`, I believe, would be to use a binning approach, with `pd.cut`:

```py
binned_data = pd.cut(expeditions.highpoint_metres, 
                     bins=[0, 6226.5, 7031.25, np.inf], 
                     right = False, 
                     labels = ["petite montagne", "moyenne montagne", "grande montagne"])

expeditions.assign(cat_month = binned_data)
```

Note that the `cat_month` for the binned approach is a categorical column

Comment: +10 nice idea about binning, but it seems slower than `select` and `case_when` (i didn't test rigorously though, just a couple quick `timeit`)

Comment: 143 µs ± 2.68 µs: `%timeit np.select(conditions.values(), conditions.keys(), default='grande montagne')`

Comment: 889 µs ± 24.6 µs: `%timeit pd.cut(expeditions.highpoint_metres, bins=[0, 6226.5, 7031.25, np.inf], right = False, labels = ["petite montagne", "moyenne montagne", "grande montagne"])`

Comment: Thanks for the test, my assumptions were wrong then

Comment: Do you mind testing for a larger sample?

Comment: ah yes, with 10M rows, `cut` takes the lead: `select` took 302 ms ± 19.8 ms, `cut` took 189 ms ± 5.04 ms

Comment: might be worth plotting later to find the inflection

Answer (score 1):

I think the `np.select()` method above is probably better, but I was already working on this so I figured I'd share.

You can make a function and then use `df.apply()` to make your new column using that function.

```py
def func(row):
    height = row['height_metres'] # your actual dataframe had this called 'highpoint_metres', not 'height_metres'
    if height < 6226.5: 
        return 'petite montagne'
    elif height < 7031.25:
        return 'moyenne montagne'
    else:
        return 'grande montagne'
df['cat_monts'] = df.apply(func,axis=1)
```

Also, notice that new final column is `df['cat_monts']` with quotes around the column name. You want the column named that string, not the column to get its name from the value of a variable with that name.

Comment: yeah `np.select` is vectorized so it's faster, but `apply` does work as well

Answer (score 0):

```
def peaks(x):
    if x < 6226.5 :
        return "petite montagne"
    elif 6226.5 < x < 7031.25:
        return "moyenne montagne"
    else :
        return "grande montagne"

    
expeditions['cat_month'] = expeditions['highpoint_metres'].apply(lambda x: peaks(x))
```